# Этимология слова "несуразный"

Tags: этимология

"Несуразный" - нелепый. А каково происхождения корня в этом слове? Не - какой? То есть, если есть несуразный, то должен быть и "суразный"?))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По В. И. Далю

> СУРАЖИЙ
> пск., твер. суразый, суразный, пск., влад., тамб. видный, пригожий, казистый. Сураждая девка. Несуразный конь. нескладный. Суразица жен., пск., сиб. сходство, подобие. И суразицы с ним нет.
> | Пара, чета к чему, подобен, противень. Подобрать к подсвечнику суразицу.
> | Суразица, суразина пск. толк, успех, порядок в деле и в работе. Сураз муж., сиб. небрачно рожденный. см. разить.
> | сиб., пермяц. бедовый случай, удар, огорченье. Сураз за суразом! беда по беде.

Answer (score 0):

В ПЦССРЯ Г. Дьяченко есть статья о слове Сур:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суразный = видный, складный, сильный, мужественный. *Несуразный* же, напротив: возможно и *хороший мужик, но не орёл*.